# Huge number of rows in pivot table (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a database of videos. Each video can have multiple categories, so I have pivot table to connect category and video together.

The problem is that the video_category pivot table has 4769325 rows, which I think is huge for such a simple thing.

Is there better way how to store the relation between video and category and still be able to query through them? It's a RoR app with Postgresql DB.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your problem. Afaik, `PIVOT` is used to transpose rows into columns.
So basically your Many-To-Many relation between videos and categories should be like this :

```
|*fk_vidID*|**fk_cateID**|
--------------------------
| videoID1 | categoryID1 |
| videoID1 | categoryID5 |
| videoID3 | categoryID5 |
| videoID4 | categoryID2 |
```

But in the case you use `PIVOT` on category table there should only have as many rows as there are videos because all existing categories for a video will be grouped on a single row.

For your performance purpose, I do not think that's there are any other ways to represent a Many-To-Many relationship in SQL.

In the case your database starts to run slowly, you will have to work on the queries itselves to speed it up. You will also probably need to make smart choices about the index fields : A decent way is to watch in your queries which fields are the most used in `WHERE` statements and set its as indexing fields.

Comment: my "problem" is that there will be couple millions of rows in pivot table. Is it common to have so many rows in pivot table?

Comment: How many rows do you have into the basic videos table and into the categories table ? Usually, `PIVOT` table contains less rows but more columns...

Comment: I have 9990 videos and 113 categories, but in the future there will be about 2milions of videos.

Comment: I don't even know how you can have 4769325 rows then since **9990*113 < 4769325**.  And that's the worst case where each video belongs to all categories.

Comment: And in the case you really use `PIVOT` on Categories you should not have more than 9990 rows.

Comment: sorry the number 4769325 would be if I would import more videos (which I'll). Right now it's **9990** videos and **23265** rows in video_category